# Sharelatex, get pdf from standalone figures without download

Tags: pdf, compiling, standalone, sharelatex

When doing bigger projects in LaTeX, it's nice to write tikzpictures and graphs in a `standalone` document, and then include the generated PDF document as a picture.

When collaborating with others, it is nice to share the documents with an editor such as `ShareLaTeX` or `overleaf`.

What is then nice to do, when combining bigger projects with sharing, would be to use both together. When using `ShareLaTeX` one can easily change the compiled document to a `standalone` figure:

[image: button in <code>ShareLaTeX</code> to change the document to compile]

However, `ShareLaTeX` does not put the PDF file produced by this in the directory, so it is not avaliable to use as an input file ;-(

I do realize that I can just compile the document I want, and then download it:
[image]

And reupload it to the directory, but to be honest this is just a big hassle.

So the question goes: Is there a better way to compile `standalone` figures in `ShareLaTeX` that get's you the PDF?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try to redefine \jobname to get a pdf with a different name. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252317/can-one-safely-redefine-jobname. But I don't know if it works also for pdf and how permanent the pdf is.

Comment: I would really like it to just put a permanent pdf with the right name in the same folder as the compiled tex file (for example if you have a `figure/` folder that you point to as your `graphicspath`

Comment: No my idea won't work, the change is fine for auxiliary files but too late to affect the pdf. And as you don't have --shell-escape on sharelatex there is imho no chance to rename the files.

Comment: That was sad :-( I actually send a message to one of the overleaf overlords, and he stated that this feature should be avaliable in the `Overleaf 2` revamp of `overleaf` comming in may. But it's just sad that it's not here yet

Comment: thanks for looking into it though ;-)

Comment: Try including the standalone graphs using `\includestandalone` in the main file and use `buildnew` as option for the `standalone` package in the main file. This way the main file compiler run will call a sub-compiler run to produce the PDFs. If this doesn't work, then you might keep using the source directly (i.e. simply remove `buildnew`)