# Cross referencing doesn't show anything

Tags: cross-referencing

I have two files; one is `main.tex` and the other is `supplement.tex` and I want to reference table label from `supplement.tex` to `main.tex`, I do the following in `main.tex`:

```
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{supplement}
```

No error has shown and I got like this `Table ??` (the number didn't appear)

Any help please, I tried different ways while searching but none of them succeed with me.

Comment: Pls give a full compilable example, with this info we can't get started

Comment: supplement.aux which comes into being when compiling supplement.tex needs to be available. (Make sure to have compiled supplement.tex as many times as needed for having everything matching out correctly.)

Comment: Are you using the `hyperref` package?

Comment: It like this really, put those two lines up and I have a text like: jkjkjfj Table \ref{fig1} kkjkjkj; and fig1 in supplement.tex. That's is @vaettchen

Comment: No I didn't, I just use what I write in the question @samcarter

Comment: See [here](https://texblog.org/2016/08/23/adding-references-from-an-external-file/) and [here](https://carleshf.netlify.com/post/cross-referencing-between-different-files-with-latex/) for some caveats

Comment: @SaraWasl That is good, hyperref would require another package.

Comment: What you mean by "supplement.tex needs to be available"? it's there (already created and have some tables and text inside) @UlrichDiez

Comment: if you mean that I should add also \usepackage{hyperref}, I try it right now but nothing change @samcarter

Comment: not supplement.tex but supplement.aux .  When you compile supplement.tex for obtaining supplement.pdf or supplement.dvi, you also get a file supplement.aux.  That file is read when processing the call to `\externaldocument` from main.tex for obtaining the referencing-data.

Comment: It seems that I didn't have it :/ how can I got/produce supplement.aux ? @UlrichDiez

Comment: @SaraWasl No, don't add it if you don't need it. It is just an often used package which would have caused problems with your code. So I wanted to know if you use it.

Comment: @SaraWasl I think for debugging it would be good if you would add two short [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your documents to your question. This way we could test if we can replicate your problem.

Comment: I assume supplement.tex itself is a compilable document. So compile supplement.tex via the latex-compiler or the pdflatex-compiler for obtaining supplement.dvi respective supplement.pdf. This compilation also delivers the auxiliary file supplement.aux. (Probably you use some fancy TeX editor or frontend for calling the latex-compiler. If you do so make sure that the auxiliary-files don't get deleted after compilation of your .tex-files.)

Comment: See the comment from 'Ulrich Diez' I didn't have supplement.aux, maybe this the problem @samcarter

Comment: I simply use overleaf for editing, I just creat supplement.tex and write down what I want, so even when I run it nothing show to me (I mean I didn't see anything on the other side) @UlrichDiez

Comment: With overleaf it won't work. overleaf imho compiles every document with the name "output". See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252317/can-one-safely-redefine-jobname. There is also a faq about this: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/How_can_I_make_the_xr_package_work_on_Overleaf%3F

Answer (score 1):

File documentA.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Section in document A}\label{Asection}
\end{document}
```

File documentB.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument[documentAPrefix-]{documentA}
\begin{document}
\section{Section in document B}\label{Bsection}

This are references to section of document A:

ref: \ref{documentAPrefix-Asection}

pageref: \pageref{documentAPrefix-Asection}

\end{document}
```

First compile documentA.tex in order to obtain documentA.pdf.

During this compilation, beneath other things, the file documentA.aux comes into being.

Keep that file. Don't have it deleted.

Then compile documentB.tex.

I suggest doing this on the shell-prompt (bash/LXTerminal/command.com/whatever you use) :

On the prompt of your shell change to the directory/folder where both documentA.tex and documentB.tex are saved. (The command for changing to a directory or folder is `chdir` or `cd` or the like.)

Then two or three times use the command `pdflatex documentA.tex`.

Then two or three times use the command `pdflatex documentB.tex`.

Besides documentA.pdf and documentB.pdf you will get files of extension .log and .aux as well. The .aux-files are of interest for the `\externaldocument`-command.  ;-)