# Issues with embedall package

Tags: embedding, embedfile

I have been trying to use the embedall package for latex but in overleaf I get...

> Package embedfile Error: File `output.tex' not found.

The MWE for this is...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{embedall}

\begin{document}

hello

\end{document}
```

On my local machine, I am playing around with emacs org mode and use...

```
\usepackage[main,include]{embedall}
\IfFileExists{./\jobname.org}{\embedfile[desc=The original file]{\jobname.org}}{}
```

in my document preamble, while compiling w/

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 latexmk -%latex -pdf -f %f -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -emulate-aux-dir -aux-directory='/tmp/latexmk' -output-directory='.'
```

but I get the error...

> Package embedfile Error: File `7acc1fb581a8a02455fd651925e667d405d48d8a.tex' not found.

If I compile tex on my local machine using the latexmkrc...

```
$pdf_mode = 1;
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode'; 
$emulate_aux = 1;
$out_dir = '.';
$aux_dir = '/tmp/latexmk';
```

I do not get errors.

How can I get my tex source embedded in my pdf file in overleaf and for org mode?

**UPDATE**

For overleaf, I tried redefining the jobname...

```
\documentclass{article}


\begingroup\escapechar=-1
\xdef\jobname{\expandafter\string\csname main\endcsname}
\endgroup

\usepackage[main,include]{embedall}
\begin{document}

hello

\end{document}
```

which worked. For org mode, I think this means I will just need to set the jobname to the current file's name without the extension.

Comment: do not use \jobname but your real file name. Systems like overleaf or latexmk change \jobname.

Comment: In overleaf I just have the embedall package, yet I still get an error.

Comment: the embedall package will probably not work, as it uses \jobname.

Comment: Could this be fixed by changing the name of jobname to be the name of the current file being processed?

Comment: perhaps, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252317/can-one-safely-redefine-jobname